# Ifstream: open a file accessible by using variables

Tags: c++, variables, directory, ifstream

While coding, I realized I had no idea about how to open a file which is located in directory that I want to specify by using variables. I looked a little bit everywhere on the internet but I was unsuccessful...

So basically, I have a file called "*2014_09_01.txt*" which is located in "*Data/2014/09*". In my code, I specify the name of the file as such (it works fine!):

```
int year = 2014, month = 9, day = 1;
char filename [256];
sprintf(filename,"%d_%02d_%02d.txt", year, month, day);
```

However, what I'd like to do is to get this file in its actual directory. The following code is wrong but this is the idea I'm talking about:

```
input.open("/Data/%d/%02d/%s",year,month,filename);
```

Is there an easy way to do such thing? That seems trivial but I can't find any way to do it properly.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think your code is only wrong because you included a `'/'` as the first character. Try removing it.

Comment: No, this doesn't change anything at all. I know that the "input.open" line is wrong because the syntax for this kind of function is wrong. But it underlines the idea that I want to specify variables to access the directory in which the file is located.

Comment: Yes, but I meant that the general idea is right I think. You can always append the path before the variable, and open that. (Without the first `/`).

Comment: I did try to remove the "/" but it didn't change anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
char filename[256];
sprintf(filename, "/Data/%d/%02d/%d_%02d_%02d.txt", year, month, year, month, day);

input.open(filename);
```

... or perhaps wrap the file path generation method in a function - modularize it

```
void getFilePath(char* outFileName, int year, int month, int day)
{
   sprintf(outFileName, "/Data/%d/%02d/%d_%02d_%02d.txt", year, month, year, month, day);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working :) I tried something similar yesterday but it didn't compile correctly.